# Meaning of adding rows matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

English is not my mother tongue and I'm studying Algebra using a book in English. This sentence came up to me in an exercise "every row of matrix $A$ adds to zero".

What does that mean, in concrete?

EDIT:

Full exercise:

> If every row of $A$ adds to zero, prove that $\det A = 0$. If every row adds to $1$, prove that $\det (A-I) = 0$. Show by example that this does not imply $\det A = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

It just means that when you add up all of the entries in any (horizontal) row of the given matrix, you get $0$.

For example, one might say that every row of $\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}1 &\color{red}{-1} \\ \color{blue}{-2} &\color{blue}2\end{bmatrix}$ adds to zero, because $\color{red}1 + (\color{red}{-1}) = 0$ and $\color{blue}{-2} +\color{blue} 2 = 0$.

Comment: Ok... And that means that each row is a linear combination of the others so the determinant will be zero, right?

Comment: I suppose it must mean that. I personally think of what such a matrix does to the "all $1$'s vector", in my example $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.